# gIntersects TopologyException in rgeos R

Tags: r, gis, polygons

I have a shapefile that represents ecoregions of the world. I am trying to determine which ecoregions are intersected by the distributions of my species of interest. I am using the latest version of R and the rgdal and rgeos packages.

I load in a list of species ranges called 'rangelist'.

I load in my ecoregions shapefile (eco), and create a list called 'regions', which contains a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object for every ecoregion:

```
readOGR(ecofile,gsub(".shp","",ecofile))->eco
regions<-list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(eco$ECO_NAME))){
    print(unique(eco$ECO_NAME)[i])
    eco[eco$ECO_NAME==unique(eco$ECO_NAME)[i],]->regions[[i]]
}
names(regions)<-as.character(unique(eco$ECO_NAME))
```

I then run a loop function that checks each range from 'rangelist' against each of these ecoregions from 'regions'. This works fine until:

```
> gIntersects(rangelist[[49]],regions[[23]])
Error in RGEOSBinPredFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, func) : 
  TopologyException: side location conflict at -78.7709 -8.18245
```

I loaded the original ecoregions shapefile into arcMap 10 and ran the "check geometry" tool but it found no problems.

The original sources of the data are:
species ranges:
http://www.natureserve.org/getData/birdMaps.jsp
ecoregions:
http://www.worldwildlife.org/science/data/item1875.html

I have temporarily posted [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34644229/gIntersect_issue.zip) a zip file containing 2 Rdata files and an R script to allow you to reproduce the error (file size is 33mb).

Does anyone have any idea as to how I can fix or get around this problem?

Comment: Any chance you can get your data to us? Or at least some of the rangelist and regions polygons? (Including the offending ones!)

Comment: data is now linked! thank you.

Comment: narrowed it down a bit more: gIntersects(rangelist[[i]],regions[[j]][c(95,148),]) - fails for your i and j, but works if you just do one of 95 or 148. I can't see whats special about 95 or 148 of regions, but rangelist[[i]] does look like two polygons joined together so that might have some effect...

Comment: If you zoom in on the point mentioned as a side location conflict there's a little bit of polygon there that might be the problem - not sure why it only shows up when intersecting with that region though. Unclean data is a pain...

Comment: Alright, the problem seemed to stem from the fact that my rangelist polygon had subpolygons, which my R script did not account for. When I dissolved it (removing that tiny polygon that you found), it worked! thanks so much for the advice!